# Unique linear combination and basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S \in \mathbb{R}^3$ be the following set of vectors

$$
v_1=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0\\
1
\end{pmatrix} ,
v_2 =\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
1\\
1
\end{pmatrix},
v_3 = \begin{pmatrix}
0\\
1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Let $W$ be a subspace of  $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined as

$$
\displaystyle W  = \{ \begin{pmatrix}
\alpha\\
\beta\\
\beta
\end{pmatrix} \mbox{where} \hspace{1mm} \alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R} \}
$$

We can show that every vector in $W$ is a unique linear combination of $v_1,v_2,v_3$ (the combining factors in fact being $\alpha,\beta-\alpha,\alpha$ respectively). Moreover, $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are linearly independent.

This would suggest that $v_1,v_2,v_3$ form a basis for $W$ and therefore, dimension of $W$ is $3$. However, every $w \in W$ can be written as

$$
W \displaystyle = \{ \begin{pmatrix}
\alpha\\
\beta\\
\beta
\end{pmatrix} = \alpha \begin{pmatrix} 
1\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix} + \beta \begin{pmatrix}
0\\
1\\
1
\end{pmatrix} \}
$$

suggesting $W$ has $2$ basis vectors and is $2$-dimensional !

What is the error in reasoning here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the definition of basis is that the proposed set is actually contained in the vector space under consideration.

In your case, neither $v_1$ nor $v_3$ are in $W$, so the set $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ fails to satisfy all of the requirements for a basis.